# Codeigniter securing certain pages based on user account

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing a system whereby a user is a member of a Client account. There are 5 or 6 clients, and each client has a number of users. When a user logs in, the site is styled to the client they are a member of.

I have a function "view_campaign":

```
function view_campaign($campaignID = FALSE){
    $this->load->model('client_model');
    $this->load->model('campaign_model');

    $data['main_content'] = 'campaign_overview';

    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

}
```

So in the URL for example we have .../campaign/view_campaign/21 (for example). This will mean that the user gets to their campaign which has an ID of 21.

But how can I make it so it's secure i.e. users that are members of another client cant view the campaign? They could just change the URL and view campaigns related to other clients...

Thanks

Comment: do you have campaign - users relationship in db? If so, just check the condition like logged in user is assigned to this campaign.

Comment: You can maintain a relation : Campaign and ids of users that are allowed to view that campaign. If a non-authentic user tries to open just throw them bad URL by authentication condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a broad question, I'm not sure what your database structure is but you want to do something like...

When the user first logs in you want to save their user ID and their client ID in a session.  Then you want to have a function in your campaign model that gets the client ID a campaign belongs to.

Your `view_campaign` function would look something like

```
function view_campaign($campaignID = FALSE) {
    $this->load->model('client_model');
    $this->load->model('campaign_model');

    //Get the user ID and client ID from a session or something
    $userId = $this->session->userdata('userId');
    $clientId = $this->session->userdata('clientId');

    //Call a function in your model to see if the user belongs to the client
    $campaignClientId = $this->campaign_model->getClient($campaignID )

    //If the client ID the campaign belongs to matches the client ID the user
    //belongs to then they can view it
    if($campaignClientId === $clientId ) {
        $data['main_content'] = 'campaign_overview';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    } else {
        //Redirect to another page
    }
}
```